# How to exclude pattern in <match> for fluentd config?

Tags: regex, ruby, kubernetes, fluentd

I want to output all in null, except the one pattern in **match**. I know there are some ways to do that via @labels for example, but i exactly want to exclude pattern in **match**.

I want to do like this:

```
<match {all tags except **events**}>
```

**What i did:**

I know i can use Ruby expressions in **match** like this:

```
<match #{tag.match(/^.*event.*$/) ? "fake_tag" : "**"}>
  @type null
</match>
```

**Logic:** "If current tag has pattern - set fake_tag for skip this **match**, else set ** for output all in null"

But this expression doesn't work because there is no variable $tag in ENV. As i understood Ruby expression can't use config variables like ${tag}.

Maybe i can set ENV variable before **match** step?

Like this:

```
<filter **event**>
  #{ENV["FLUENTD_TAG"] = ${tag}}
</filter>

<match #{FLUENTD_TAG.match(/^.*event.*$/) ? "fake_tag" : "**"}>
  @type null
</match>
```

These are my thoughts but maybe there are simpler ways.

The question is - how to exclude pattern in **match** ? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop one, leave everything else:

```
<match what.you.want.to.drop>
  @type null
</match>
<match **>
  # process everything else
</match>
```

Drop everything except one:

```
<match what.you.want.to.stay>
  # process here or send to a label
</match>
<match **> # Optional block. It will be dropped anyways if no other matches, but with a warning printed to a fluentd log.
  # Drop everything else explicitly to avoid warning.
  @type null
</match>
```

Comment: Yes it is good way, but in my case I can't use several matches I have to use only one :) are there ways for drop everything except one in one match? Via ruby expression for example ?

Comment: `drop everything except one` is exactly what precise match is doing. Updated my example.