# Fluentd | how to drop logs of specific container

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluentd

we have Fluentd running on our multiple K8s clusters. and with Fluentd we are using Elasticsearch to store our logs from all remote K8s clusters.
there are a few applications for which we do not want Fluentd to push logs to Elasticsearch.

for example, there is a pod running that has container named testing or it has labels as `mode: testing`. and we want FluentD to not process the logs of this container and drop them.

looking for suggestion on this how we can achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981063/how-to-exclude-pattern-in-match-for-fluentd-config) is an explanation to do that with `Fluentd`.

But I would like to recommend another tool developed by the same team: [Fluent Bit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/kubernetes). It is very light (needs <1MB of memory as Fluentd needs about 40MB), and more suitable for K8S, you can install it as a damonset (a pod on each node), with a Fluentd deployment (1-3 replicas), every Fluent Bit pod will collect the log and forwards it to a Fluentd instance which aggregate it and send it to ES. In this case, you can easily filter the records using the pod annotations ([more info](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/kubernetes)):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: apache-logs
  labels:
    app: apache-logs
  annotations:
    fluentbit.io/exclude: "true"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: apache
    image: edsiper/apache_logs
```